# How to use two schemas with Apollo?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

According to apollo docs, you have to download your schema by setting the url in a file named **apollo-codegen-config.json**:

```
"schemaDownloadConfiguration": {
"downloadMethod": {
    "introspection": {
        "endpointURL": "https://myApp.com/v1/cats/_/graphql",
        "httpMethod": {
            "POST": {}
        },
        "includeDeprecatedInputValues": false,
        "outputFormat": "SDL"
    }
},
"downloadTimeout": 60,
"headers": [],
"outputPath": "./graphql/schema.graphqls"
```

}

The problem is when I want to use another scheme, eg. https://myApp.com/v1/dogs/_/graphql, those schemes sometimes share the same model like:

```
type State {
  country: ID!
  state: String!
}
```

then the cli returns:

```
There can be only one type named "Date".
```

How can I add the two schemas?, and how does it know when to point to **/cats** and **/dos**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use two configs, one for each schema. We download and generate all files in two directories. That “solve” your Apollo problems.

Now you will have a Swift problem as generated classes will collide. We use an extra step after generating to rename all type from one of the two directories. We add some prefix. You can even prefix both: DogsState… and CatsState…